# Xcode project use main interface from dynamic framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I created a dynamic framework(need to be dynamic, as it includes .swift files), the framework works fine an I can load my storyboard programmatically from the appDelegate like this:

```
    let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "DynamicLibrary")
    let s = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboardName", bundle: frameworkBundle)

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    self.window!.rootViewController =  s.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

But when I change of ViewController (moving to another screen inside the same .storyboard) the app crashes.
I wonder if it is possible to include a .storyboard from a dynamic framework as a Main interface in the project settings. Or what is the best alternative to load a .storyboard from a dynamic framework as a main storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem to my issue, just answering here because it may be useful to someone else.

At the beginning my storyboard and my assets were all in my project, therefore I had no problem to load/link them. But when I moved them into a dynamic library (Cocoa framework touch) my app started crashing and it was because of the way that I was loading the assets that weren't any more in my project but in my framework.
So when I had everything in my project I was doing this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_grey_2.png"]
```

But after moving it to my framework I had to updated to:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"bar_grey_1" ofType:@".png" inDirectory:nil]]
```

Jut a comment about dynamic frameworks, they are not supported in iOS7 and apple will refuse to accept any app aiming iOS7 with dynamic frameworks.

Comment: The question is tagged "swift": please write your code examples in Swift. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to provide more specific information on what error is being encountered than "the app crashes".

But in general, problems with loading Interface Builder files from bundles are due to classes referenced in the file not being linked into the output because the linker can't pick up on a reference to a bundle. The canonical remedy for that is to add `-all_load -ObjC` to Other Linker Flags. Which has its own attendant set of issues, but is somewhere to start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this time I could avoid to add this evil flag. :)